# Find entity with unique id without knowing its type EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Is there any way to find an entity with its unique id without knowing its type ?

For example write

```
DataContext.Find(Id);
```

instead of

```
DataContext.Set<T>().Find(Id);
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do that? What problem are you trying to solve? BTW there's no such thing as a universal unique ID in a database. Each table has its own columns that define its primary key. You can't (actually, you **don't** want to) write a query that would search all tables in a database to find a row by ID. Such a query would be extremely slow, lock all tables and freeze any application that uses this database

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank for your help  . As a result , As this is impossible I should think of another way . Any way Thanks  ;)

Comment: Whatever you want to do, there are better ways to do it. What do you really want to do? What you posted is two wrong snippets - one that doesn't exist and one that shouldn't be used. A DbContext is neither a database model nor a database connection. It's a *Unit-of-Work* including *specific entities* that are used in *specific use cases only*. Not a way to expose all tables to the client

Comment: Another way to do what????? You haven't asked anything yet, just posted suspicious  code. It looks like you're using DbContext like a database model, or trying to build the repository *anti*pattern on top of the ORM

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually I wanna be able to save comment for every product . So I made an one to many relation between comments table and products table. The problem starts where I receive the comment text and info and i want to make a relation between that comment and product  but I don't know ow to find the product between other product tables

Comment: All you need is to create the proper tables and relations then. An ORM like EF can't do things that are impossible in SQL. If a comment can only apply to a single product, you need a 1:Many relation between Products and Comments. In the database that would be a single `ProductID` column in `Comments`. In EF, this would appear as a `Product` property in the `Comment` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id is unique only within the table. You can not give Id and ask, in which table is it used...You do not want to do it this way :)

Comment: This should be a comment